# Perl array hash - strict refs

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, strict

this is probably simple for most, but I have a Perl script where I am ot using strict, and use this syntax:

```
$welcome_data[$x]{email}       = $data[0];
```

It works fine.  Now, when I enable strict:

```
$welcome_data[$x]{email}       = $data[0];
Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong??

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO Landon, hope you are able to find the answers you seek and nice to see some Perl users.  Can I ask which version of Perl you're using to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: Perl 5.8.8.     Want to thank everyone, as I now have it working.......

Comment: If you could, I’d highly suggest you upgrade to at least 5.10 or 5.12 at a minimum, but Perl 5 has much newer versions than those that address significant issues and features that will make your life easier in the long run

Answer (score 5):

```
$welcome_data[$x]{email}
```

is short for

```
$welcome_data[$x]->{email}
```

In other words, `$welcome_data[$x]` is expected to be a reference (or undef<sup>[1]</sup>). However, in your case, it contained an empty string. It's as is you were doing

```
${""}{email}
```

That's obviously not what you wanted to do. But fortunately for you, this is exactly the kind of bug strict refs is designed to catch. Now you can go fix wherever you are assigning an empty string to `$welcome[$x]`.

---

1. If it's undef, Perl will *autovivifiy* a reference to a new anonymous hash for you as if you had used

   ```
   ( $welcome_data[$x] //= {} )->{email}
   ```

Comment: Good answer.  Might want to include a link into what autovivication is as it may be a new concept to him